# Installing Java 7: "the path 'Temp;C:' contains an invalid character"

Tags: java, installation, windows-installer, java-7, failed-installation

I am trying to install Java 7u80 on Windows 10. When I attempt to install it,  get this error:

"Error 1324. The path Temp;C: contains an invalid character."

I am not sure what it means or why it is even trying to use a path with those characters in it. I have been trying to do research on this issue and so far found nothing. The solutions I found said that it is caused by a username with an invalid character in it, but my username is CF77. I do not know what to do and am looking for help.

Comment: Your `TEMP` or `TMP` environment variable is likely bad. That's usually where installation programs find the path to the temp folder. Type command `set` in a command prompt to see your environment variables.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TEMP or TMP environment variable is likely bad. That's usually where installation programs find the path to the temp folder. Type command set in a command prompt to see your environment variables. – Andreas

Answer (score -1):

Well you can easily figure out if you watch few you tube video on how to set the path variable in java after installation.
Here is the couple of link-
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+set+path+variable+for+java+in+windows+10

Comment: "after installation" I cannot even install it. The error occurs at the beginning of installation.

Comment: Well you can remove the old files from program files you will see java folder delete it  or you can do it from control panel and then re-install the  java. then set the path variable .